# Rename import name when bundling to commonjs?

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

My source code requires me to import from `module-dev` like so:

```
import { calculate } from "module-dev";
```

I am currently bundling into `commonjs` using Rollup (`format: cjs`). It is possible to rename the dependency to for example `module-prod`? So that the output would be:

```
var calculate = require('module-prod');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [plugin alias](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-alias) do the job